# Matching 3 elements at once in ocaml and converting nucleotides into acids

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm currently doing a project where I have DNA lists of nucleotides like `[T;A;C;G;G;C;T;A;G;A;T;T;T;A;C;G;C;T;A;A;T;A;T;C]` and I need to convert the nucleotides between the first chain ("START" and "STOP") into their corresponding acids. So for that I need to get the nucleotides 3 by 3 and pass them into this function:

```
type acid = Ala | Arg | Asn | Asp | Cys
           | Glu | Gln | Gly | His | Ile
           | Leu | Lys | Phe | Pro | Ser
           | Thr | Trp | Tyr | Val | START | STOP

let convert_acid (n1 : nucleotide) (n2 : nucleotide) (n3 : nucleotide) : acid =
  begin match (n1, n2, n3) with
  | (A, A, A) -> Phe | (A, A, G) -> Phe | (A, A, T) -> Leu  | (A, A, C) -> Leu
  | (G, A, A) -> Leu | (G, A, G) -> Leu | (G, A, T) -> Leu  | (G, A, C) -> Leu
  | (T, A, A) -> Ile | (T, A, G) -> Ile | (T, A, T) -> Ile  | (T, A, C) -> START
  | (C, A, A) -> Val | (C, A, G) -> Val | (C, A, T) -> Val  | (C, A, C) -> Val
  | (A, G, A) -> Ser | (A, G, G) -> Ser | (A, G, T) -> Ser  | (A, G, C) -> Ser
  | (G, G, A) -> Pro | (G, G, G) -> Pro | (G, G, T) -> Pro  | (G, G, C) -> Pro
  | (T, G, A) -> Thr | (T, G, G) -> Thr | (T, G, T) -> Thr  | (T, G, C) -> Thr
  | (C, G, A) -> Ala | (C, G, G) -> Ala | (C, G, T) -> Ala  | (C, G, C) -> Ala
  | (A, T, A) -> Tyr | (A, T, G) -> Tyr | (A, T, T) -> STOP | (A, T, C) -> STOP
  | (G, T, A) -> His | (G, T, G) -> His | (G, T, T) -> Gln  | (G, T, C) -> Gln
  | (T, T, A) -> Asn | (T, T, G) -> Asn | (T, T, T) -> Lys  | (T, T, C) -> Lys
  | (C, T, A) -> Asp | (C, T, G) -> Asp | (C, T, T) -> Glu  | (C, T, C) -> Glu
  | (A, C, A) -> Cys | (A, C, G) -> Cys | (A, C, T) -> STOP | (A, C, C) -> Trp
  | (G, C, A) -> Arg | (G, C, G) -> Arg | (G, C, T) -> Arg  | (G, C, C) -> Arg
  | (T, C, A) -> Ser | (T, C, G) -> Ser | (T, C, T) -> Arg  | (T, C, C) -> Arg
  | (C, C, A) -> Gly | (C, C, G) -> Gly | (C, C, T) -> Gly  | (C, C, C) -> Gly
  end
```

So my idea is to get the first 3 nucleotide of the list, convert them by passing them into the function, and concatenating the returned list into a new list, but I don't know how to do that. Here is what I have done so far in pseudocode:

```
let rec dna_to_chain (x : dna) : acid list =
  match with x
  | hd::tl -> convert_acid hd
  | _ -> do nothing
```

I would like to get the first 3 elements of the list x, pass them into the convert_acid function, then calling dna_to_chain with the rest of the list till I reach the "STOP" acid.

After that I need to do an another function to convert each dna into chains (each sequences of nucleotides between a START and STOP), and put them into a list of list of acids with a similar function without using recursion (I guess that I need to use the recursive function that i need to do first).

Anyone know how I could finish my code and make it works? Thanks!

EDIT:
I now have the following function

```
let rec dna_to_chain (x : dna) : acid list =
      match with x
      | n1::n2::n3::tl -> (convert_acid n1 n2 n3) :: dna_to_chain tl
      | [] -> [] ;;
```

`dna_to_chain [T;A;C;G;G;C;T;A;G;A;T;T ; T;A;C;G;C;T;A;A;T;A;T;C]` returns `[START; Pro; Ile; STOP ; START;Arg;Leu;STOP]` but how can I get the first acids between the first START and STOP? I'm thinking of making an another function and doing pattern matching again but how do I know that the START that I'm matching is the first one of the chain for example?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Your pattern `hd :: tl` only matches against the first nucleotide (`hd`). You might think about looking at three of them instead with a pattern like `nt1 :: nt2 :: nt3 :: tl`. You can translate 3 nucleotides into an acid. You also need to translate the tail, i.e., you need to make some kind of recursive call using `tl`. Then you can put together the two results.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for! I didn't know it was possible. Now I'm matching n1::n2::n3::tl -> (convert_acid n1 n2 n3) :: dna_to_chain tl. I don't know how to get only the first sequence between START and STOP though. I'm thinking about making a first function to perform the convertion with START and STOP and a second function to only keep the acid between START and STOP. I'm not sure if it's the correct way of how to do it.

Comment: Please note that your `dna_to_chain` function's pattern matching is not exhaustive. It doesn't account for lists with 1 or 2 elements. Also, it's stylistic, but I find it very helpful (and generally idiomatic) to match the empty list case first.

Answer (score 0):

First don't put the `START` in your result list in your `dna_to_chain` function. You can ignore them because they are useless for the rest of your problem.

Then you just have to write a "split" function, which is a good exercice.

Split take a `l ('a list)` and `v ('a)` as argument and return the sublists between each occurence of `v` in the list. For exemple :

```ml
split [2;3;3;1;2;3;4;5;1;2;1;3;1;8;9] 1;;
- : int list list = [[2; 3; 3]; [2; 3; 4; 5]; [2]; [3]; [8; 9]]
```

Once you did that you just have to use `List.map` with your `dna to chain function` on the result of

```ml
split (dna_to_chain (*your dna*)) STOP
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But what if the DNA doesn't start with START ? I need to consider this case and raise an exception if the DNA isn't valid (no START -...- END)

Comment: Ok I thought you were assuming that the DNA was valid.
Then you'll have to code a sort of split function which check that first chain is a START, and split the lists on a ``STOP`` and check that the following element of each ``STOP`` is a ``START`` (and it skip it) or that it's the end of the DNA

Comment: So i should use a fold_right for that ? I made a function that filters START and STOP elements to only keep the acids using Liste.fold_right but i don't know how i can build sublists

Comment: You can do it in tail recursion or with an aux function, if you really don't know how to do it I can show you how to make the general split function

Comment: I've been playing around and trying to implement such a function but unfortunately I can't get anywhere

Comment: I don't know how I can "keep in memory" that I've already seen a START when i iterate through the list, and then if i've already seen a start and see a STOP, return true. I was thinking about making a "is_valid" function for that, and maybe applying it on the general split function for each sublist, and only returning the first sublist for the first question and all the valid sublist for the other question where i need to return each valid chain.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I don't know if that's the good way to answer on SO so if I should edit my old answer instead of writing a new one just tell me.

So here are 2 versions of the split code I talked about in my previous answer. I hope it'll help you to figure how to achieve your modified split function. The first one use 2 recursive function and the second one is tail recursive

```ml
let rec split v = function
  | [] -> []
  | t -> let a, b = goNext v t in 
      if a <> [] then a :: split v b else split v b
and goNext v = function
  | x :: xs -> if x = v then [], xs else 
      let a, b = goNext v xs in x :: a, b
  | [] -> ([], []);;
  
let split2 l v = 
    let rec aux acc buff = function 
        | x :: xs -> if x = v 
            then
              aux [] (if acc <> [] then List.rev  acc :: buff else buff) xs
            else
              aux (x :: acc) buff xs
        | [] -> List.rev @@ if acc <> [] then List.rev acc :: buff else buff
     in aux [] [] l;;
```

Both function ignore empty list between 2 occurrences of `v`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is useful as an answer, because a comment is a bit limited to detail this.

```
let between start_tok stop_tok lst =
  let (_, _, result) = List.fold_left 
    (fun (start_seen, acc, overall_acc) x -> 
      if start_seen && x = start_tok then 
        (true, [], overall_acc) 
      else if start_seen && x = stop_tok then
        (false, [], overall_acc @ [acc])
      else if start_seen then
        (true, acc @ [x], overall_acc)
      else if x = start_tok then
        (true, [], overall_acc)
      else
        (false, acc, overall_acc))
    (false, [], [])
    lst
  in
  result
```

We fold over a list of type `'a list` having provided start and stop tokens of type `'a`. Our initial value to the fold is a tuple containing whether the start token has been seen, an accumulator, and an overall accumulator. As it goes, if it's between a start and stop token, it adds to the accumulator. When it hits a stop, that accumulator gets added to the overall accumulator. At the end we use pattern matching to just access the overall accumulated list.

There's nothing here to handle errors when either the start or stop are not encountered. I'll leave that as a further exercise for you.

I find the confines of a fold are a great way to look at what information actually needs to be communicated across iterations over a list.